# Считывание данных из файла в очередь через односвязный список

Tags: c++, очередь, односвязный-список

У меня есть queue.h, queue.cpp и main.cpp. А так же есть файл, в котором находятся 4 типа данных, написанные через пробел в одной строке и в определенной последовательности. Таких строк несколько, где меняются лишь значения данных. Одно из главных значений это первое, по которому собственно и будет происходить поиск строки.

Пример:

```
1 B 14 15.68
2 B 3 23.54 
1 S 5 13.2
3 B 4 9.99
```

Я помещаю данные из файла в очередь и уже в main.cpp начинаю с ними работать. Примечательно то, что у меня объявлено 3 объекта класса "Queue", ибо судя по первой цифре у меня есть 3 типа строк, которые могут повторяться.

Проблема в том, что при считывании и вызове например строк с первым символом 1, у меня вылетает строка с символом 2...

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::fstream input;
    input.open("inventar.txt");
    int option, key, quantity;
    char type, choise;
    double price;

    Queue item1;
    Queue item2;
    Queue item3;
        

    do {
        std::cout << "i > инвентарь\n"<< "n > считать данные\n" << "s > statistika\n" << "e > exit\n" << "Ваш выбор: ";
        std::cin >> choise;
        Node* temp = new Node();
        Node* front;
        Node* rear;
        Node* n;


        switch (choise) {
        case 'i':
            std::cout << "Zadajte Vas vyber: ";
            std::cin >> option;

            if (option == 1) {
                item1.display();
            }
            else if (option == 2) {
                item2.display();
            }
            else if (option == 3) {
                item3.display();
            }
        case 'n':
            if (!input) {
                std::cout << "Chyba v nacitavani suboru!" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                //nacitavanie zo suboru, ci ze pridanie prvkov do zoznamu
                while (!input.eof()) {
                    if (temp->key == 1) {
                        input >> key >> type >> quantity >> price;
                        temp->key = key;
                        temp->type = type;
                        temp->quantity = quantity;
                        temp->price = price;
                        item1.enqueue(key, type, quantity, price);
                    }
                    else if (temp->key == 2) {
                        input >> key >> type >> quantity >> price;
                        temp->key = key;
                        temp->type = type;
                        temp->quantity = quantity;
                        temp->price = price;
                        item2.enqueue(key, type, quantity, price);
                    }
                    else {
                        input >> key >> type >> quantity >> price;
                        temp->key = key;
                        temp->type = type;
                        temp->quantity = quantity;
                        temp->price = price;
                        item3.enqueue(key, type, quantity, price);
                    }
                }
            }
            continue;
        case 'e':
            std::cout << "Koniec programu" << std::endl;
            input.close();
            return 0;
        }
    } while (choise != 'e');
}
```

queue.cpp

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool Queue::isEmpty() {
    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void Queue::enqueue(int vKey, char vType, int vQuantity, float vPrice) {
    Node* ptr = new Node();
    ptr->key = vKey;
    ptr->type = vType;
    ptr->quantity = vQuantity;
    ptr->price = vPrice;

    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (front == NULL) {
        front = ptr;
        rear = ptr;
    }
    else {
        rear->next = ptr;
        rear = ptr;
    }
}

void Queue::dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "Queue is Empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (front == rear) {
            free(front);
            front = rear = NULL;
        }
        else {
            Node* ptr = front;
            front = front->next;
            free(ptr);
        }
    }
}

void Queue::show() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << front->key;
    }
}

void Queue::display(){
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "Queue is empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        Node* ptr = front;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            if (ptr->key == 1) {
                //cout << key << type << quantity ....
                cout << ptr->key << " " << ptr->type << " " << ptr->quantity << " " << ptr->price << endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            else if (ptr->key == 2) {
                cout << ptr->key << " " << ptr->type << " " << ptr->quantity << " " << ptr->price << endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            else if (ptr->key == 3) {
                cout << ptr->key << " " << ptr->type << " " << ptr->quantity << " " << ptr->price << endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

queue.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int key, quantity;
    char type;
    float price;
    Node* next;
};



class Queue {
public:
    Node* front = NULL;
    Node* rear = NULL;

    Queue() {
    };
    bool isEmpty();
    void enqueue(int vKey, char vType, int vQuantity, float vPrice);
    void dequeue();
    void show();
    void display();
};
```

Comment: Честно, вообще ничего не понятно. Приведите пример входных данных, данные которые возвращает ваша программа и данные которые вы ожидали увидеть.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков В файле у меня 4 строчки, каждая начинается с новой строки, как я описал выше. И в каждой строке есть первый символ - цифра: один, два или три . В main.cpp, через switch я сначала записываю каждую строку в очередь отдельно, а далее так же через switch я ввожу, к примеру 1 и мне должна программа выдать все строчки с данной цифрой в начале, это как ее номер. Аналогично с цифрой 2 и 3 при вызове.

Comment: То есть `1 B 14 15.68, 2 B 3 23.54, 1 S 5 13.2, 3 B 4 9.99` это 4 строчки? И все таки, что выводит программа и что вы ожидали увидеть в результате.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да, это строчки, каждая с нового ряда записана в файле. Вот я ввожу 1 и мне должно выдать: `1 B 14 15.68` `1 S 5 13.2`. То есть эти две строчки, где в начале стоит единица. Аналогично с двойкой и тройкой.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков И в принципе оно выводится, но если я задаю, мол мне нужны строки под номером 1 , а мне выдает 2 и 3, когда задаю, что мне нужен номер 2, выдает 2, здесь все нормально, но вот при номере 3 мне выдает обе строчки с номером 1

Comment: Надо было в вопросе тогда и расположить их на разных строчках, чтобы понятней было)

Comment: Теперь не понятен код в `main.cpp`, что за `case 'n'`, что за `temp`. Выложите пожалуйста минимальный код, который можно запустить у себя.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков пожалуйста. Буду очень признателен, не могу понять в чем дело

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вы хотели сделать так:

Считываете первую цифру и относительно неё заносите в одну из очередей.

Но изначально у вас `temp->key` не прочитан, и попадает под `else`. Считывает первую строку и вносит в 3 очередь что уже не правильно.

А далее в `temp->key` записана 1 от предыдущей записи и все дальше ломается.

Сначала считываете `temp` потом проверяете. Так же у вас куча ненужного кода было, немного уменьшил:

```
while (!input.eof()) {
    input >> temp->key >> temp->type >> temp->quantity >> temp->price;
    if (temp->key == 1)
        item1.enqueue(temp->key, temp->type, temp->quantity, temp->price);
    else if (temp->key == 2)
        item2.enqueue(temp->key, temp->type, temp->quantity, temp->price);
    else
        item3.enqueue(temp->key, temp->type, temp->quantity, temp->price);
}
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь, конечно ошибка очень глупая)